# Differences between Prettier CLI and VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier, prettier-vscode

I tried to align VSCode extension and my local version of Prettier CLI in my project in order to get same results from both tools.

- Prettier VSCode Extension : v9.10.4 (depends on prettier `>=2.8.0`)
- Prettier : v2.8.0

With the following settings

```json
// .vscode/settings.json
{
  "prettier.documentSelectors": ["**/*.svg"],
  "prettier.resolveGlobalModules": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "prettier.requireConfig": true,
  "prettier.prettierPath": "./node_modules/prettier",
}
```

```json
// .prettierrc
{
  "printWidth": 80,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "arrowParens": "always",
  "bracketSameLine": false,
  "overrides": [
    {
      "files": ["*.tsx"],
      "options": {
        "parser": "typescript"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And here is my test file

```js
import * as React from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [indicatorStyle, setIndicatorStyle] = React.useState<React.CSSProperties>({});
}
```

The "Format Document" option from VSCode gives this result

```js
import * as React from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [indicatorStyle, setIndicatorStyle] = React.useState<
    React.CSSProperties
  >({});
}
```

And the result from Prettier 2.8.0 CLI

```js
import * as React from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [indicatorStyle, setIndicatorStyle] =
    React.useState<React.CSSProperties>({});
}
```

What should I do to get the same result instead (the result from Prettier CLI looks better in this case) ?

Thank you.

Comment: To be sure with prettier cli to use the .prettierrc  use the --config  compilation flag. `prettier --config pathToYour.prettierrc`    Note that if .prettierrc isn't in the root directory of your project without the --config it won't be found and the vscode default settings of prettier should be applied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be related to a cache problem. After restarting VSCode I get the same results on both tools now!